# Как грамотно обрабатывать ответы сервера при использовании jQuery Ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, интерфейс

Добрый день. В своих сайтах и пр.скриптах (парсерах например) я использую JQuery Ajax() для отправки данных форм в основном. Вот у меня возникает такой вопрос, а как грамотно обрабатывать ответы от php скриптов?

Пример, при отправки письма. Я через JQuery Ajax() отсылаю данные формы скрипту. Письмо может уйти или не уйти. В зависимости от этого я отдаю JQuery Ajax() ответ, например

```
<span class="success" > Письмо ушло </span>
```

или

```
<span class="error" > Произошла ошибка </span>
```

А дальше в функции success в jQuery Ajax() пишу всякие проверки на наличие элементов с классом success или error и показываю пользователю соответствующие сообщения. У меня есть чувство, что я делаё всё как-то замудрённо, не правильно, что есть более изящные методы, но какие - понятия не имею. Подскажите а как вы обрабатывайте такие ответы, как выстраиваете логику поведения?

Answer (score 1):

Так и обрабатываем.
Пример из документации
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Пока возвращаешь html ничего лучшего у тебя не будет, можешь конечно поиграться со статус кодами, но ничего хорошего тебя с ними не ждет.

Простейшее решение - возвращать json с полями messageClass, messageText и создавать сообщение на клиенте. Ручками или с помощью темлейтов (mustache.js).

```
<span class="{{messageClass}}" > {{messageText}} </span>
```

Хипстерское решение  - использовать json + angular.js :)

Comment: надо попробовать, я думал за JSON на самом деле, но не знал как к нему подступиться.

Comment: <?php
       $arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);
   
       echo json_encode($arr); // {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
  ?>